# Python : ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3,3) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (270,3)

Tags: python, matrix, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to save multiple confusion matrix instance of each fold in 10 fold cross validation.
my code look like this :

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)
conf_matrix = np.zeros([3,3])

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
    
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    pred = model.predict(X_test)
    conf_matrix[train_index] = confusion_matrix(y_test, pred)

conf_matrix
```

but it returns this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-8a1e0e2223f7> in <module>()
      9     model.fit(X_train, y_train)
     10     pred = model.predict(X_test)
---> 11     conf_matrix[train_index] = confusion_matrix(y_test, pred)
     12 #     print(confusion_matrix(y_test, pred))
     13 

ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3,3) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (270,3)
```

which is weird, because if I run `print(confusion_matrix(y_test, pred))` the output is 3x3 matrix that look like this :

```
[[4 2 3]
 [4 8 1]
 [1 3 4]]
[[3 6 1]
 [4 5 1]
 [5 1 4]]
[[7 3 4]
 [4 4 1]
 [0 1 6]]
[[3 1 2]
 [2 9 1]
 [3 2 7]]
[[4 4 2]
 [2 8 2]
 [0 2 6]]
[[7 6 1]
 [4 4 2]
 [0 3 3]]
[[4 1 3]
 [2 5 3]
 [3 1 8]]
[[1 4 3]
 [2 5 1]
 [2 3 9]]
[[7 5 2]
 [2 3 3]
 [2 3 3]]
[[4 2 1]
 [2 6 0]
 [3 5 7]]
```

where did I go wrong?

Edit 2 : I've tried @user1424589 suggestion, and change my code like this now

```
conf_matrix = np.zeros((10,len(y_test),len(y_test))) #10 because I want it to caontain 10 confusion matrix
```

but it still return the same error, it return this error now

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3,3) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (270,30,30)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that that what you have told it to do is assign that output array into a slice of conf_matrix which has shape (3,) you need to shape conf_matrix such that it can accept the result of confusion_matrix(y_test, pred).

Comment: and how can I do that? since I only got value for (y_test, pred) inside my for loop